# Make transition between two Menus with UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, menu, uiscrollview, uistackview

[image: screenshot]

I want to have 2 menus (the other one will be the same as the one shown in the screenshot, but it will contain other items).

Each menu is in its own `UIStackView`.

I've decided to rule out the `UIPageViewController` and instead use `UIScrollView` because it's the behaviour I want.

How can I put both menus inside of `UIScrollView` and make a nice animation?

Comment: What sort of animation are you wanting?

Comment: @SoOverIt Whatever, let's say slide or show or whatever..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you avoiding UIPageViewController because of the complexity? Because if you are there is a much easier way to accomplish the same gesture controlled transition using UIScrollView's pagingEnabled property

Based on what I see in the screenshots...

```
var size                                      = CGSize()
    size.height                               = self.view.frame.height
    size.width                                = self.view.frame.width * 2

let scrollView                                = UIScrollView()
    scrollView.frame                          = self.view.frame
    scrollView.contentSize                    = size
    scrollView.pagingEnabled                  = true
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false

    nav.center.y                              = scrollView.frame.height / 2
    nav.center.x                              = scrollView.frame.width / 2
    nav2.center.y                             = scrollView.frame.height / 2
    nav2.center.x                             = nav.center.x  + scrollView.frame.width

    scrollView.addSubview(nav1)
    scrollView.addSubview(nav2)

self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
```

Comment: Yeah, I am avoiding UIPageViewController because of its complexity. The problem is very small and I think it's too much code to achieve little functionality in my project. Can you provide me instructions for doing things that you've described above? Thanks!

Comment: I went ahead and added some code, let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Let me explain everything I've done, so you can provide the best support:
here is the screenshot of the storyboard: http://prntscr.com/9r9pqg
this first menu should be in the middle horizontally and vertically where it is now. the second menu should replace him when scrollview is activated.
here is the hierarchy: http://prntscr.com/9r9qef
inside of uiscrollview i have 2 navs(2 uistackviews)
here is the screenshot of the class: http://prntscr.com/9r9r1e

Comment: Updated again, should be good to go. Please let me know if you have any other questions or need any clarification.

Comment: Now I have no functionality, everything remains the same.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to do scrollview.addsubview(nav1) and for nav2!
now it works, but everything isn't layed out properly. http://prntscr.com/9ra1f1

Comment: I changed it a little bit, let me know if that does it. Maybe the scrollView's center property is set correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100900/discussion-between-dsieczko-and-dragos-strugar).

Answer (score 0):

@dsieczko did fantastic job answering my question. I'm not experienced with AutoLayout, so that was the problem. My final code looks something like this:

```
    import UIKit

class MainMenuViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet var nav2: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet var nav: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet var pageControl: UIPageControl!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        /* MAIN MENUS */
        var size                                      = CGSize()
        size.height                               = self.nav.frame.height
        size.width                                = self.view.frame.width * 2

        scrollView.frame                          = self.view.frame
        scrollView.contentSize                    = size
        scrollView.pagingEnabled                  = true
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false


        nav.center.y                              = scrollView.frame.height / 2
        nav.center.x                              = self.view.frame.width * 1.5
        nav2.center.y                             = scrollView.frame.height / 2
        nav2.center.x                             = nav.center.x  + scrollView.frame.width + 400

        scrollView.addSubview(nav)
        scrollView.addSubview(nav2)

        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)

        /* MAIN MENUS */

        // Change the Navigation Bar Color to Red
        navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.79, green: 0.19, blue: 0.19, alpha: 1)

        // Change the Navigation Bar Font to Lato
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes =
            [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(),
                NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Lato-Semibold", size: 20)!]
    }

  }
```

And my layout something like [this](http://prntscr.com/9rdvxp):

If anyone encounters a problem like this, I will gladly help with my exp with this.